# Not able to figure out the logic behind sense circuitry of a AC/DC converter

Tags: power-supply, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

In the below circuit, why would there be 2 extra diodes (D3 and D4) to sense AC input voltage?
If D3 and D4 act as rectifier, wouldn't it be sufficient to directly sense at the output of bridge rectifier?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqiYpn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The circuit does not make a sense. Measured current pass two diodes of rectifier.

Comment: @devnull: Corrected the typo. Looks like it is sensing the AC voltage ( Peak, average  or instantaneous) is not clear.

Comment: It is what it is - do you know what circuit connects to "Sense voltage" and GND - without knowledge of that the circuit and how it might interact with the PFC circuit, it's impossible to 100% say without guessing. You have more information, yes?

Comment: Yes, It uses the sense voltage to check whether the input ac volatge is within limits.

Comment: I suppose this isn't a high-current circuit? or the AC sense voltage isn't required to be very precise? I'm asking because referring the sense to GND which is connected to P2 of the PFC may offset the reading. Depending on the exact circumstances, it may be totally neglible, but it also may show up as a huge noise in the vsense reading. I'd say this 'sense' circuit is like "four-Wire Kelvin measurement" (load=PFC, measurement=sense/GND) just with 2+1 wires instead of 2+2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be smoothing capacitors after the main diodes so that the voltage there does not reflect the actual input voltage.

Any such capacitors will be small as the main ones will be after the PFC but may result in excessive error.

Comment: The main capacitor is at the output of PFC. Only very less capacitance is present at the input of PFC

Comment: @DivyaK.S - I agree. Maybe there is some back feeding through the PFC that upsets accurate measurements.

Answer (score 3):

In a PSU, the bridge rectifier output goes to a smoothing capacitor to produce a DC level with (ideally) little ripple. Your diagram shows C1.

If other circuitry wants to detect the AC supply presence, the smoothed DC isn't always good place to get it. The capacitor will hold the DC level up for some amount of time.

The two diodes can go into a single resistor or a potential divider. That gives a nice full-range AC waveform for supply voltage measurement, zero-crossing detection or whatever else 'sense voltage' is to be used for. I've done this myself.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the bridge rectifier is shunted by small filtering capacitors. This distorts the waveform from a rectified sine wave to a combination of a sine wave and ramp. The sense voltage is measured in the RMS sense, and if you added a filter capacitance from sense voltage terminal to common, you'd convert rectified AC into DC peak. And the sense voltage's RMS value would be too high, and some circuit protection would "trip" or indicate high voltage, when there's no problem.